# how to show dropdown list in multiple view blade using laravel

Tags: laravel

I have created a dropdown list using Laravel. Now I want this list to show on multiple pages. Like a Login.blade and register.blade.

Controller:

```
class DropDownController extends Controller
{
    public function dropdownlist()
    {

        $rolls['roll'] = roll::get(["roll_id", "roll"]);
        return view('auth.register', $rolls);   
        // return view('auth.login', $rolls);
    }
   
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('register',[DropDownController::class,'dropdownlist']);
```

Login Blade:

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Users</label>
                    <select name="roll">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Users</option>
                        @foreach($roll as $row)
                        <option value="{{$row->roll_id}}">{{$row->roll}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <span class="text-danger">
                        @error('roll')
                        {{ $message }}
                        @enderror
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Now I want this list to show on multiple pages. Like a Login.blade and register.blade.

Comment: Use this: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show a dropdown list in multiple view blades using Laravel, you can use every function like that-

```
$rolls=roll::select('roll_id','roll')->get();
return view('auth.register', $rolls);
```

and also use in login controller-

```
$rolls=roll::select('roll_id','roll')->get();
return view('auth.login', $rolls);
```

now use this variable then show in pages
and if you try this then create global function in user model and use anywhere

```
<div class="form-group">
                    <label>Users</label>
                    <select name="roll">
                        <option value="" selected disabled>Select Users</option>
                        @foreach($rolls as $row)
                        <option value="{{$row->roll_id}}">{{$row->roll}}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                    <span class="text-danger">
                        @error('rolls')
                        {{ $message }}
                        @enderror
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't the same function work?

Comment: error show undefine $roll

Comment: if undefine $roll then check the $rolls value get or not- like dd($rolls); in controller and if get vaue then compact value in a return view. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding correctly you would be best to create your dropdown as a component and using a view composer to pass the required variables into it.

Some documentation of view composers:
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers

within the pages you require the dropdown you can either use `@include('dropdown-menu')` or `<x-dropdown-menu />`

Using the view composer will allow you to pass the variables into the component view that you define.

Comment: i am not understand your answer.

Comment: Please add supportive information in your answer from the link shared

Comment: So you'd need to create a new class called `ComposerServiceProvider` which extends `ServiceProvider`.

After this add a view composer to the view you have created with the dropdown component: 

`View::composer('components.dropdown', DropDown::class);`

within the view composer you'd pass the variables which are required for that file:

`$view->with([
            'rolls' => Rolls::get()
        ]);
`